Powershell alias for executable files
The following command starts Midnight Commander in Powershell
cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander\mc.exe"

Source :https://github.com/adamyg/mcwin32
How can I set this up so that I can start it via Alias PowerShell?
## This command does not work. 
Set-Alias mc "cmd /K C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander\mc.exe"


Shouldn't start mc the executable anyway? If not you may add the path to it to your path environment variable

In short: Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as bash, you cannot include pass-through arguments in a PowerShell alias definition - you need a function for that. PowerShell aliases are simply alternative names for other commands, with no ability to "bake in" arguments. E.g., to define a short command bar that invokes command foo with fixed argument baz while passing all other arguments through, use function bar { foo baz @args } - see the linked duplicate for more information.

GitHub issue #12962 is a proposal to someday support Bash-style aliases in PowerShell too.

However, in the case at hand - assuming that you don't need a stay-open (/K) cmd.exe session to mediate your mc.exe calls - you can define the alias directly with the target path: Set-Alias mc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander\mc.exe"

Aliases in PowerShell aren’t quite the same as in other environments, such as bash - PS aliases can only effectively “rename” the command, but cannot themselves pass parameters or modify parameter handling - that is, the default aliases dir and ls are used exactly like the standard cmdlet Get-ChildItem, including using Get-ChildItem’s parameters.
To make an “alias” pass parameters, wrap the complete command in a PS function:
function mc {
    cmd /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander\mc.exe"
}

but as @Olaf says in the comment to the question, it’s better to add the program’s folder to your PATH and just allow mc to search the path and run.

Wonderful, it works.
Thank you so much.

Escaping the spaces and parentheses:
set-alias mc C:\Program` Files` `(x86`)\Midnight` Commander\mc.exe

Or add to the path:
$env:path += ';C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander'


Note that there's no need for metacharacter-individual escaping, given that you can use quoted strings, e.g. Set-Alias mc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander\mc.exe"
